# Regular Expression - Forbid string, of any size, that contains only one character repeatedly

Tags: regex, html, html-input

I am looking for a regex that will prevent the insertion of a string, with **arbitrary size**, that contains only one character repeatedly.

For example these strings are **invalid**

```
aaaaaaaaaa
222
bbbbbbbb
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
```

but these are **valid**

```
aaaaaaa2
@@@@@@@@@@@@f
b2222
```

I want it for an HTML5 text input:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control"  placeholder="name" pattern="...">
```

Comment: Why bother using regex?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try the following:

```
^(?!^(.)\1+$).*$
```

It'd help if you also provide information about which tool you'll be using.